# '|' or operator meaning in vuejs src code "vnode.js"?

Tags: vue.js

I want to know the | operator meaning, could anyone explain?
here's some short code snippet in src/core/vdom/vnode.js

```js
export default class VNode {
  tag: string | void;
  data: VNodeData | void;
  children: ?Array<VNode>;
  text: string | void;
  elm: Node | void;
  ns: string | void;
  context: Component | void; // rendered in this component's scope
  functionalContext: Component | void; // only for functional component root nodes
  key: string | number | void;
  componentOptions: VNodeComponentOptions | void;
  child: Component | void; // component instance
  parent: VNode | void; // component placeholder node
  raw: boolean; // contains raw HTML? (server only)
  isStatic: boolean; // hoisted static node
  isRootInsert: boolean; // necessary for enter transition check
  isComment: boolean; // empty comment placeholder?
  isCloned: boolean; // is a cloned node?
  isOnce: boolean; // is a v-once node?
```

Comment: They're flow type definitions, a project which adds types to javascript https://flowtype.org/

Answer (score -1):

Here `|` is an OR unary operator.

```
ns: string | void;
```

which means `ns` is of type `string`, but if `string` is not defined due to some reason, it will be of type `void`. This should be just for precaution if it is not defined in some browser version.